# C++ Class with 2 template arguments, function with 1 argument

Tags: c++, class, templates, arguments, containers

Is there any way to call a class member function that takes only 1 template argument instead of 2?

I would like to write some code like this:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void Container<int, N>::quick_sort() {

}
```

Comment: Why not `template<size_t N>
void Container<int, N>::quick_sort() {

}`

Comment: @ThomasSablik template argument list must match the parameter list

Comment: If you intend to have a special sorting algorithm for `int`-s, then use *tag-dispatching*

Comment: There is a lot of context missing here, but your template arguments are not for the function, they are for the class. Do you want a special function for containers of `int`?

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes exactly

Comment: Related to [partial-template-specialization-for-constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61992005/partial-template-specialization-for-constructor) and [partial-specialization-for-one-method-in-the-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61795331/partial-specialization-for-one-method-in-the-class)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot partial specialize a method, you could partial specialize the whole class, but require some duplication.

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
class Container
{
    // Some code ...
    void quick_sort();
};

template <typename T,size_t N>
void Container<T, N>::quick_sort()
{
   // ...
}

// Class specialization
template <size_t N>
class Container<int, N>
{
    // Some similar/same code...
    void quick_sort();
};

template <size_t N>
void Container<int, N>::quick_sort()
{
   // ...
}
```

As alternative, C++17 allows

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
class Container
{
    // Some code ...
    void quick_sort()
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int, T>) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }

};
```

For prior versions, regular `if` would probably produces error (both branches should be valid, even if not taken).

So tag dispatching is an easy approach (SFINAE is another one):

```
template <typename> struct Tag{};

template<typename T, size_t N>
class Container
{
private:

    void quick_sort(tag<int>)
    {
        // ...
    }
    template <typename U>
    void quick_sort(tag<U>)
    {
        // ...
    }

public:
    void quick_sort()
    {
        quick_sort(Tag<T>());
    }
    // Some code ...
};
```